# .npmrc throws error "Expected a JSON object, array or literal."

Tags: npm, .npmrc, yarn-v2

Yarn creates info output like this:

```sh
info esbuild-android-arm64@0.13.4: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-arm64@0.13.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-arm64@0.13.4: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.13.4: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
[...]
```

I want yarn to suppress output like that via a `.npmrc` file adding `loglevel=silent`.

However, in VSCode I get this message in the `Problems` tab:

```sh
.npmrc
   Expected a JSON object, array or literal.
```

[image]

But as per documentation key/value pairs are a valid way for npmrc configuration:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/npmrc

Also, it does not help telling yarn to be silent.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Wrong type association in VS Code? Try telling it that file should be INI, e.g. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

Comment: Indeed that is a way to get rid of VScode's message. However, it still does not tell yarn to reduce output in the console... any ideas? And could you please turn you comment into an answer, so I can upvote it? Thanks!

Comment: (Never mind, Yarn can be silenced, when using "--silent" in the proper position.)

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#dont-use-npmrc-files